# Error when installing Breeze.Server.Webapi2?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nuget, breeze

I'm trying to install the **Breeze.Server.Webapi2** Nuget package for my completely empty solution. However I keep getting the following error:

> Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.1.2' to
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.0.0' failed. Unable to find a version
>   of 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData' that is compatible with
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.0.0'.

As suggested in the answer of I've tried installing **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData** and then **Breeze.Server.WebApi2**. I received the following error when installing **Breeze.Server.WebApi2**:

> Install-Package : Updating 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.0' to
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.0.0' failed. Unable to find a versio n
>   of 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData' that is compatible with
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.0.0'.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Hi Jamie. Mabye it's the same problem with in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108085/nuget-breeze-server-for-web-api-2-0-install-error

Comment: @EdiG.
Hi Edi. Thanks for your reply but I've tried the answer already. I've updated my question with the response.

Comment: Hi Jamie, I can't repro this behavior. Can you provide additional information? What version of Breeze are you trying to install? the latest Breeze, 1.4.17, uses Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.1.0 and not 5.0.0. Based on the message it looks like Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.1.2 is already installed, so the solution is not completely empty. (by the way, creating an empty web application with the Web API package did not fail either) Providing the exact steps to repro the issue will help pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had an outdated version of Visual Studio. Once I updated it I received no errors.